# How to encode a node gd image to base 64 without saving the file?

Tags: node.js, image, buffer

I am manipulating some images using [`node-gd`](https://y-a-v-a.github.io/node-gd/), trying to upload to twitter via their api.

Doing it like so works fine:

```
fs.readFileSync('test.png', { encoding: 'base64' })
```

But I was hoping there was a way to do this without saving it to a file then loading it again.

Other people suggest doing something like this:

```
var gd = require('node-gd');
var img = gd.openPng('test.png');
var buff = Buffer.from(img.pngPtr(), 'binary');
var b64 = buff.toString('base64');

console.log(b64);
```

But when I do this, I get an error saying `TypeError: binary is not a function` which makes no sense to me.

Full error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/test.js:16
var buff = Buffer.from(img.pngPtr(), 'binary');
                  ^

TypeError: binary is not a function
    at Function.from (native)
    at Function.from (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/test.js:16:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems buffer.from() is relatively new (v 5.10.0), here is the syntax for earlier versions:

```
new Buffer(pngFile.pngPtr(), 'binary')
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but nevertheless:

```
var gd = require('node-gd');
var img = gd.openPng('test.png');
var buff = img.pngPtr(-1, true);
var b64 = buff.toString('base64');

console.log(b64);
```

Where for `img.pngPtr(-1, true)`, `-1` is default compression and `true` will return a Buffer.